# How to call a method of the child component in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have `Foo.razor`:

```
@foreach (var item in items) {
  <p>@item</p>
}

@code {
  private List<string> items = new List<string>();

  public void Append(string item) => items.Add(item);
}
```

If I have `Bar.razor`:

```
<Foo/>

@code {
  public void SomeMethod() {
    ...
  }
}
```

how can I call `Append("something")` from `SomeMethod()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to call child component method from parent component in blazor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60041619/how-to-call-child-component-method-from-parent-component-in-blazor)

Answer (score 5):

Below is the example using `@ref` attribute. `@ref` provide a way to reference a component instance. Please refer to: [Blazor Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

### Foo

```
@foreach (var item in items)
{
    <p>@item</p>
}

@code {
    private List<string> items = new List<string>();

    public void Append(string item) =>items.Add(item);

    public void Refresh()
    {
        this.StateHasChanged(); //To refresh component after we have added items
    }
}
```

### Bar

```
<Foo @ref="foo"/>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="SomeMethod">Add items</button>

@code {

    Foo foo;

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        foo.Append("item1");
        foo.Refresh();
    }

}
```

Note:

> `The component variable is only populated after the component is rendered and its output includes the component's element. Until that point, there's nothing to reference. To manipulate components references after the component has finished rendering, use the OnAfterRenderAsync or OnAfterRender methods.`