# How to call child component method from parent component with foreach

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I've seen examples of how to call a child component's method from a parent component using the `@ref` attribute, but when I try to use it with a `foreach` loop, only the last rendered component's method gets called and not all of them. Below are examples of my components.

**Parent component:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" @onclick="BtnSyncAll_Click">Run<button>

@foreach(var site in Sites)
{
    <Site @ref="SiteView" @Code="@site"></Site>
}

@code {
    protected Site SiteView;
    protected List<string> Sites { get; set; } = new List<string>
    {
        "A00001",
        "A00002"
    };

    protected async Task BtnSyncAll_Click()
    {
        await SiteView.Sync();
    }
}
```

**Child component (Site.razor):**

```
<div>
    <p>@Code>/p>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    protected async Task Sync()
    {
        await ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you declare `Sites`?

Comment: "only the last rendered component's method gets called and not all of them" what do you mean by "all of them", you want to call `await SiteView.Sync()` of all `Site` components?

Comment: @Vencovsky - yes, I want to call `SiteView.Sync()` from all instances of `Site` component in the foreach loop. Updated my question with the declaration of `Sites`.

Comment: @Jason Ayer, I guess my answer was not useful to you, right ? Shall I delete it ? Answers with zero reputation are never read by users. I never read answers unless they pass the first pre-condition of being accepted.

Comment: @enet - Apologies, I saw it but have not had time to test it in my application yet. It looks promising, please do not delete it. I will test it here soon and get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: Pardon me if I am missing something but I feel the sync method would be better utilized in the parent to sync/update child parameters. Why not just create a new param that starts null and then overrides (takes precedent over) the code param if(newParam != null).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both you and enet are overcomplicating things...

The most "politically correct" approach to do what you pretend may be creating an independent service to signal every child component when has to resync, and inject it by means of DI, but this would take too much plumbing for this, and maybe in your case it's not worth it. So here you have a simpler approach:

First, remove the Sync method from your component, change it for this:

```
[Parameter]
public int SyncSignaler { get; set; }


protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(300);
    output = $"This is Site: {Code}";
    //StateHasChanged();
}
```

Then, declare a integer variable on your parent component, pass it to the childs, and increment it every time you want them to refresh.

In your parent component:

```
@foreach (var site in MySites)
{
    <Site Code="@site.Code" SyncSignaler="@syncIndicator"></Site>
}


@code {
 
    private int syncIndicator = 0;

    protected async Task BtnSyncAll_Click()
    {
        syncIndicator++;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

etc...
```

Please, let me know if it worked. Cheers!

Comment: You know what, this was actually the method I thought about using, but I thought SURELY there should be an easy way to call a method on a child component in a loop...nope. This is how I'm going to do it. Thank you.

Comment: This is by far the best approach.  Kudos and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code sample describing how you should do it:

### Site.razor

```
<div>
    <p>@Code</p>
</div>
<p>@output</p>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    private string output;
    private static int index;

    public async Task Sync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(300);
        output = $"This is Site: {Code}";
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" @onclick="BtnSyncAll_Click">Run</button>

@foreach (var site in MySites)
{

    <Site @ref="@site.SiteRef" Code="@site.Code"></Site>
}

@code {
     private List<MySite> MySites;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        MySites = new List<MySite> { new MySite { Code = "A00001", SiteRef = new Site() },
                                                 new MySite { Code = "A00002", SiteRef = new Site()} };
    }

    protected async Task BtnSyncAll_Click()
    {
        foreach (var site in MySites)
        {

            await site.SiteRef.Sync();
        }


    }

    public class MySite
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public Site SiteRef { get; set; }
    }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: You know what, I was thinking that would probably be the issue. Would any Generic Collection item work or does it specifically have to be an `Site[]` item?

Comment: I just realized, I have no idea how to write this in code. I made SiteView `List<Site>` object but what goes into `@ref` now?

Comment: I've updated my answer. This works and does what you want... Don't hesitate to ask questions.

Comment: I will check this out soon.